# gwt-log issue with app engine

Tags: java, logging, gwt

Hi I am having trouble displays logging messages on App engine.
Currently, I am using gwt-log to log messages, I basically followed getting started page on gwt-log but no logs are logged in app engine management console's log section. When I thrown an exception from the server, I see header sent to server:
[Lcom.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.ClientStackTraceElement;/

However, it is not logged in app engine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.....
Please help.

Here are my configurations:

logging.properties:

```
.level = WARNING

DataNucleus.JDO.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Persistence.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Cache.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.MetaData.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.General.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Utility.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Transaction.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Datastore.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ClassLoading.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Plugin.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Enhancer.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.SchemaTool.level=WARNING
```

web.xml

remoteLoggerServiceImpl
    com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServiceImpl

remoteLoggerServiceImpl
    /bam/gwt-log

gwt-xml:

remoteLoggerServiceImpl
    com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServiceImpl

remoteLoggerServiceImpl
    /bam/gwt-log

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had the following code to your file appengine-web.xml?

```
<!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```